# Complex logic as ToolTip on the Angular UI Grid's cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using [**Angular UI-Grid**](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/117_tooltips).

This is the grid implementation:

**JS**

```
    var statusCellTemplate =
    '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><span ng-
if="row.entity.statusDetails.length>=2" title="My Tooltip">[Multiple Statuses]
    </span></span></div>';

vm.propertyListGridOptions = {
                appScopeProvider: vm,
                flatEntityAccess: false,
                fastWatch: true,
                showHeader: false,
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        name: app.localize('ListingStatus'),
                        cellTemplate: statusCellTemplate,
                        width: 240,
                    },
                 ],
                data: []
            };
```

I need to show the `ToolTip` by using below logic.Can you tell me how to implement such a logic with the above `cellTemplate` ?

```
  _.each(row.entity.statusDetails, function (s) {
                            vm.statusValues += s.status.name + ', ';
                        });
```

**Note :** `_.each` can be a `ng-repeat` on angular.